# Is there mongodb mapping converter for generic message

Tags: spring-integration

Is there mongodb mapping converter for generic message.
No argument constructor not available for generic message.

```
.11:47:30.937 [http-nio-9080-exec-1] ERROR o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[.[dispatcherServlet] - Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [messageHandler]; nested exception is org.springframework.data.mapping.model.MappingInstantiationException: Failed to instantiate org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage using constructor NO_CONSTRUCTOR with arguments ] with root cause 
java.lang.NoSuchMethodException: org.springframework.messaging.support.GenericMessage.<init>()
    at java.lang.Class.getConstructor0(Class.java:3082)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredConstructor(Class.java:2178)
    at org.springframework.beans.BeanUtils.instantiateClass(BeanUtils.java:104)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ReflectionEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ReflectionEntityInstantiator.java:61)
    at org.springframework.data.convert.ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.createInstance(ClassGeneratingEntityInstantiator.java:83)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:251)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.read(MappingMongoConverter.java:231)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.readValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1186)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter.access$200(MappingMongoConverter.java:78)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1134)
    at org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter$MongoDbPropertyValueProvider.getPropertyValue(MappingMongoConverter.java:1097)
```

Also I am trying following config of mongotemplate 
Please advise if correct

```
public MongoTemplate messagingMongoTemplate() throws Exception {
    MongoTemplate mongoTemplate=null;
    try {
        DbRefResolver dbRefResolver = new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory);
        MappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();

        MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver,mappingContext);

        CustomConversions customConversions = new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new MongoDbMessageBytesConverter()));
        mappingMongoConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions);
        mongoTemplate=new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory,mappingMongoConverter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting with version `3.0` it is recommended to use `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore` as that provides more options for customization, including a `Converter` for `Message`.

Out-of-the-box Spring Integration provides `MongoDbMessageBytesConverter`, which has become `public` since `4.2.10` and is used by default if there is no any external customization for the `ConfigurableMongoDbMessageStore`.

Comment: thanks for the response but MongoDbMessageBytesConverter is not a MappingMongoConverter.

Comment: added stacktrace in the question

Comment: Does this MongoDbMessageBytesConverter need to be used as transformer OR this can be tied to mongodbfactory as a mappingmongoconverter

Comment: MappingContext mappingContext = new MongoMappingContext();

            MappingMongoConverter mappingMongoConverter = new MappingMongoConverter(dbRefResolver,mappingContext);

            CustomConversions customConversions = new CustomConversions(Arrays.asList(new MongoDbMessageBytesConverter()));
            mappingMongoConverter.setCustomConversions(customConversions);
            mongoTemplate=new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory,mappingMongoConverter);

Comment: Yes, the last one is correct. Look at Spring Data MongoDB for more information about mapping

Comment: But still getting same stacktrace

Comment: Ok. Now you have to share the `MessageStore` config